# Data Series- drop str from list

Tags: pandas, series

I have this data:

[image]

I want to have only first name of device (for example: `Samsung` or `Alcatel`) in my data frame. How can I do this?

Comment: Did my solution work? :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You'd use `.str[0]`:

```
android['Device'] = android['Device Model'].str.split().str[0]
```